# Want to bring values of matched data with SUMIF from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

So code is below

```vb
Sub SumIF_test()

    thwb = "Macro Open Another Worksheet.xlsm"
    thws = "Sheet1"
    Workbooks(thwb).Worksheets(thws).Range("B5").Select
    ActiveCell.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Workbooks("CreditAnalystofBank.xlsx").Worksheets("REBanco").Range("A:A"), Range("A7"), Workbooks("CreditAnalystofBank.xlsx").Worksheets("REBanco").Range("H:H")) = a MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

Gives error like 'expected =' that's why I added variable a, I need to land the data on specific cell. Now, it gives Object doesnot support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VBA SumIf

- You can do this in a number of ways.
- The first example shows how to do it by putting all values into constants. At this stage, it might lack readability.
- The second example shows how to do it by putting only the workbook and worksheet names into constants and variables. It becomes somewhat more readable.
- The first example also shows how you can use `Application.SumIf` or `WorksheetFunction.SumIf` (no need for `Application` with `WorksheetFunction`). There may be differences in doing it one way or the other for other functions, which I wouldn't say is the case here.
- s - Source , d - Destination

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumIfFull()

    ' Constants
    
    Const swbName As String = "CreditAnalystofBank.xlsx"
    Const swsName As String = "REBanco"
    Const srAddress As String = "A:A" ' Range
    Const ssrAddress As String = "H:H" ' Sum Range
    
    Const dwbName As String = "Macro Open Another Worksheet.xlsm"
    Const dwsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const drAddress As String = "B5" ' Result
    Const dcAddress As String = "A7" ' Criteria
    
    ' Workbook, Worksheet and Range (Cell) References
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(swbName)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srAddress) ' Range
    Dim ssrg As Range: Set ssrg = sws.Range(ssrAddress) ' Sum Range
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(dwbName)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    Dim dcCell As Range: Set dcCell = dws.Range(dcAddress) ' Criteria
    Dim drCell As Range: Set drCell = dws.Range(drAddress) ' Result
    
    ' Write
    
    ' Late-Bound
    drCell.Value = Application.SumIf(srg, dcCell.Value, ssrg)
    ' Early Bound
    'drCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(srg, dcCell.Value, ssrg)

End Sub

Sub SumIfWbWs()

    ' Constants
    
    Const swbName As String = "CreditAnalystofBank.xlsx"
    Const swsName As String = "REBanco"
    
    Const dwbName As String = "Macro Open Another Worksheet.xlsm"
    Const dwsName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    ' Only Worksheet and Workbook References
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(swbName)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(dwbName)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    
    ' Write
    
    ' Late-Bound
    dws.Range("B5").Value _
        = Application.SumIf(sws.Range("A:A"), dws.Range("A7"), sws.Range("H:H"))

End Sub
```